# Swift threading multiple tasks?

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-queue

I have this label that is supposed to display a username. Now, I have done quite a bit of IOS developing, however threading is still a bit unclear to me. How would I make sure this code finishes:

```
User(name: "", email: "", _id: "").getCurrentUser(userId: userId)
```

Before this gets excecuted?:

```
self.nameLabel.text = currentUser.name
```

I have been fumbling with `DispatchQueue` but I can't seem to figure it out...
Thx in advance!

Comment: Assuming that `getCurrentUser` performs an asynchronous network operation then you need to pass a closure to `getCurrentUser` and update the label in that closure,  it without more information on what that function is, it is impossible to say for sure.

Comment: If this call is async, then normally it would also take a completion closure as an argument, or provide some other way to be notified when it finishes. If the `getCurrentUser` method is part of your app (instead of a third-party framework), the right answer is probably to make sure it uses this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send a notification in your `getCurrentUser()` method and add an observer in your UIViewController to update the label.

```
public extension Notification.Name {
    static let userLoaded = Notification.Name("NameSpace.userLoaded")
}

let notification = Notification(name: .userLoaded, object: user, userInfo: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
```

And in your UIViewController:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(self.showUser(_:)),
        name: .userLoaded,
        object: nil)

func showUser(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let user = notification.object as? User,
        notification.name == .userLoaded else {
            return
    }
    currentUser = user
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.nameLabel.text = self.currentUser.name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DispatchGroups to do this, as one solution. Here is an example:

```
// create a dispatch group
let group = DispatchGroup()

// go "into that group" starting it
group.enter()

// setup what happens when the group is done
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    self.nameLabel.text = currentUser.name
}

// go to the async main queue and do primatry work.
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    User(name: "", email: "", _id: "").getCurrentUser(userId: userId)
    group.leave()
}
```

Comment: The `enter` needs to go before the `notify`, or else the `notify` will execute immediately.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I corrected the example. That is what I get from doing it from memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate **synchronous** from **asynchronous** tasks.
Typically, a synchronous task is a task *blocking* the execution of the program. The next task will not be executed until the previous one finishes.
An asynchronous task is the opposite. Once it is started, the execution passes to the next instruction and you get typically the results from this task with delegating or blocks.

So without more indication, we can't know what exactly `getCurrentUser(:)` do...

According to Apple :

> DispatchQueue manages the execution of work items. Each work item submitted to a queue is processed on a pool of threads managed by the system.

It is not necessarily executing work items on background threads. It is just a structure allowing you to execute synchronously or asynchronously work items on *queues* (it could be the main queue or another one).

Comment: Thx for the comment! sorry that I didn't put it in: `getCurrentUser()` performs an async http request. However, the method is in another file so I can not access the `nameLabel` in that file.